# SQL Hasmany Query select 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables which I am trying to query.

**Stock_Table**

- Stock_Code
- Stock_Name
- Physical_Stock

**Order_Table**

- Order_Date
- Quantity
- Stock_Code

I'm after all stock records where the physical stock is greater than 0 and the last date it was ordered.

I thought the following query would do it but this duplicates the stock records per how many orders there are.

```
SELECT
    Stock_Code,
    Physical_Stock,
    Order_Date
FROM Stock_Table
INNER JOIN Order_Table
    ON Stock_Table.Stock_code = Order_Table.Stock_Code
WHERE Physical_Stock <> 0
```

Comment: you need `max(order_date)` and `group by stock_code, Physical_stock`  and you say stock > 0 but show not equal <> to 0 which is it?

Comment: Physical stock can't be less than 0 so <> 0 does work logically.

Comment: K, I've worked with many systems where stock could be negative  (example we shipped the product that just arrived; but hand't completed the system updates showing it was checked it in yet.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Greater than 0 or <> 0 which is it?

You just need to use aggregate function max() to get the max order date since multiple orders could be placed for a given stock code.  and since you use aggregation, a group by is needed for the non-aggregated columns.

```
SELECT Stock_Code, Physical_Stock, max(Order_Date)
FROM Stock_Table 
INNER JOIN Order_Table 
  ON Stock_Table.Stock_code = Order_Table.Stock_Code
WHERE Physical_Stock <> 0
GROUP BY Stock_Code, Physical_Stock
```

Answer (score 2):

```
--So, what is happening, we use ROW_NUMBER() OVER and PARTITION BY
--ROW_NUMBER() Adds in the number for that particular record based on the PARTITION BY
--stock_code then orders the records by the order_date Descending
--Then selects from the subquery each record with row number = 1
--This produces the first record for each unique stock_code
--and since it is ordered by order_date descending, you get the most
--recent purchase
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT st.stock_code, physical_stock, order_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
   st.[stock_code] ORDER BY [order_date] DESC) AS [Row_Number]
   FROM Stock_Table AS st 
   INNER JOIN Order_Table AS ot 
   ON st.stock_code = ot.stock_code
) AS x
Where x.physical_stock <> 0 AND x.[Row_Number] = 1
```

Comment: Would this work?  I didn't think you could limit a window function result in the select in the where since the where executes before the select; which is why I often see winnow functions in subqueries or CTEs.

Comment: @xQbert I updated my answer and tested this with test data, it indeed returns each unique stock item with it's most recent purchase date.

Comment: @xQbert Yeah, thanks for the correction, I'm not so good at writing these things without having it inside of SQL, lol

Comment: You'll get there, write so many of these over the years you begin to recognize patterns/faults in patterns.

Comment: @xQbert thanks for the encouragement, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the cross apply top 1 solution:

```
SELECT Stock_Code, Physical_Stock, Order_Date
FROM 
    Stock_Table
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 Order_Date
        FROM Order_Table 
        WHERE Stock_Table.Stock_code = Order_Table.Stock_Code
        order by Order_Date desc
    )q
Where Physical_Stock <> 0
```

This enables you to bring more columns from the most recent orderdate if you wish, too.

Comment: Yep this is indeed a useful technique to get additional columns from the order table.  Just has to be on a somewhat newer version of SQL server.  Not sure when Cross apply came in... 2012?  wow 2005... great solution I need to update my use of these techniques.. I'm too oldschool.

Answer (score 0):

Using GroupBy

```
SELECT 
  Stock_Table.Stock_Code, 
  Max(Physical_Stock) As Stock, 
  Max(Order_Date) As LastDate
FROM  
  Stock_Table INNER JOIN 
  Order_Table ON Stock_Table.Stock_code = Order_Table.Stock_Code
Where Physical_Stock > 0
Group By Stock_Table.Stock_Code
```

Comment: why max(physical_Stock) it's coming from stock table whereas order_date is order_Table, thus the 1:M  issue is on the order table.  Seems odd to get a max on a value that would be unique assuming stock_code is a PK....

Comment: It does seem odd, but since it is coming from the "1" side of the relationship it works and I think it's faster than a GroupBy with multiple columns.